Frame handlers ( pre and post ) : Crash trying to rebuild the scene for each new frame
Instead of using keyframing, I try to rebuild a scene at every frame. It means deleting all the animated objects and rebuilding them. Their geometry and properties depend on frame number and the value of an animated custom property (x).
For this, I use :
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_handler_pre)

... which lets me execute a function ( a handler named frame_handler_pre ) before the frame is built.
The crashes at render are so frequent that this file is not really usable.
To isolate the problem, for this post solely, I built a file as small as possible, with one object depending on a custom variable x and frame.
My code :
import bpy
import math
import numpy as np 
    
def frame_handler_pre(scene):
    # Not used (yet)
        
def frame_handler_post(scene, depsgraph):
    dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    frame = scene.frame_current

    M = scene.objects["M"]
    current_world = scene.world.evaluated_get(depsgraph)  # HERE
    x = current_world["x"] 
    M.location = (x,x,x)

    if bpy.data.objects.get("Point") is not None:
        obj = bpy.data.objects["Point"]
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)        
    
    #create mesh and object
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions=2, radius=1.0, calc_uvs=True, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(x,0,0), rotation=(5*x, 0.0, 0.0), scale=(1,1,1))

    object = dg.view_layer.objects.active   # error : 'Depsgraph' object has no attribute 'active_object'
    object.name = "Point"    
                                    
#    Event Listener   Frame Change
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()  # just once
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_handler_pre)
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(frame_handler_post)

Any idea to improve this ?
T H A N K S !
My  file :


Hello, I think def frame_handler_pre(scene): can take an optional despgraph argument like frame_handler_post. eg change it to def frame_handler_pre(scene, depsgraph):

"instead of using keyframing, I try to rebuild a scene at every frame. " Why?

@Gorgious Hi, and Thanks but adding the argument  :  AttributeError: 'Depsgraph' object has no attribute 'active_object'

Hi Martynas, I thought I would have more freedom and more clarity. Having to keyframe vert's position for instance seemed heavy and tedious. Being able to develop an object's geometry slowly frame by frame for (another) instance seemed interesting ...
But if the price is too heavy in terms of trouble and carshes I'll go for keyframing ...

Depsgraph doesn't have active_object as a member but it does have a view_layer as a member which has an objects.active you can access. See https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html#bpy.types.Depsgraph

Even if you want different meshes for each frame, you can use keyframe animation for hiding and showing them. Handlers may not work well when rendering an animation(depending on what you do with them), because context is different during rendering. You may encounter unforeseen problems, if you decide to do things different way than they are done. It's best to at least make a decent attempt to use existing functionality before going to totally custom solution with Python.

Yes Martynas, this is was a little voice in my head is telling me, louder and louder. But at least I wanted to give it a try. And considering the amount of posts about it, here and there, I feel that I am not the only one, and that solving this could be useful to others ...
Last reason, but not least : I am stuborn.

object = dg.view_layer.objects.active  ends the two symptoms I was dealing with. But the rendering is unstable and often crashes.

Just one question about the good practices in this forum : As a correction ( Thanks @Gorgious ) helped to narrow down the problem, is it pertinent to edit the main post and change the question and its title ?

Yes, if it adds value to the question, you can modify the title and body. However if it totally changes the meaning of the question, you should post a new question instead of overwriting this one

@Martynas , I am right now building a version of the file with keyframed animation. It gives me another reason to use the frame handler approach : you need to build a function to construct the object, and ANOTHER one to keyframe their vertices. Both functions have the geometry of the object in common (the order of the vertices their index ), so changing anything in this structure needs to be repercuted to both fuctions ... unless you make a third called by the two others, and compatible with them ... well. It is not at straight forward as the frame handler approach. What do you think ?

I think you need to step away for a minute and rethink the bigger picture. Do you need Python to generate the geometry, might it be easier to just model different versions? Is it maybe possible to use Geometry Nodes for procedural modelling/animation? Even if you need Python, can you maybe think of a way to do that more efficiently? If you want help with this, it might be worth to consider asking another question describing the full context of the higher level task.

Well, the purpose is to illustrate some math courses. I defitely need Python. Geonodes is great for a lot of things, but not for this.
I have just finished the big file with keyFraming istead of handlers. It is able to draw and animate curves ( morphing ), lines and points. It is satisfying. So it is a good day of work. Thanks for your advices ...

@Nicolas I had a look at your file that I missed previously. It makes little sense, to be honest. It's completely unclear what you are actually trying to do though. I would advice to consider asking for help providing the full context, maybe in the future questions. This is clearly an XY problem. You could save yourself some frustration. It seems to me you don't have much knowledge about functionality in Blender and so you tend to do things the hard way. People here can help, but only if you provide full context.

@Martynas "It's completely unclear what you are actually trying to do" Sorry  as I built this minimal example for this post. Indeed, its purpose was not to "do something" except isolating the problem. The full context was too much. That said, in your answers, since the beginning, I can't help seeing an slight desire to put people down in a place where people help each other out ... which is here possible as Gorgious did it, writing far less than you.   Please accept that what you don't understand is not necesseraly weak and absurd, it might simply be poorly explained ... my bad.

These are all comments though. The question did not get any answers. Sorry about my rudeness, I am still trying to help though. And I do believe that I am still right in this case and more context would benefit the question and it is still possible you are missing something here. The code in the file makes no sense - you don't need to delete and add a new object just to change it's position and rotation, so there is a chance you might be doing something absurd here, it's simply not possible to rule that out by looking at the code example.

But you are right - I don't know if it is weak or absurd. If you know for sure that's what you need, that's fine, if you don't and decide to provide more context, I will however attempt to figure it out no matter my tone or pleasantness. I hope this sort of balances things out.
